# Cobordism Groups an the Pontryagin-Thom Construction

Tags: differential-topology, cobordism

I am confused by the statement that $\Omega^\text{framed}_1(S^3) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ which I came across as an application of the Pontryagin-Thom construction for showing that $\pi_3(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  I understand that there is a $\mathbb{Z}$'s worth of framings on a given knot that are not pairwise framed cobordant to each other but why does the type of knot not seem to matter?  My guess is that all knots in $S^3$ are cobordant, is this the case and if so why?

Thanks!

Comment: All knots are cobordant to the unknot by the existence of Seifert surfaces.

Comment: @Mike Miller gives a great answer. Also note that the cobordism doesn't take place in $S^3$ but in $S^3\times[0,1]$. The extra dimension gives you also another way to unknot